# Render div every time state is changed, using setinterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render div when state is changed. I am changing the state after each 2 sec. I also have two buttons to start and end the interval. But when i press start button it renders the div only once and also pressing end button does not do anything.Please help.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


export default function Progressbar(props) {
    const [texts, setTexts] = React.useState([]);

    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        progressdiv:{
            width:'100%',
            height:'50px',
            overflow:'auto',
        }

      }));
let interval =null;

const handlestart=()=>{
    interval=setInterval(function() {
        let line = "asad";
        let arr = [...texts];
        arr.push(line);
        setTexts([]);
        setTexts(arr);
      }, 2000); 
}

const handleEnd=()=>{
    clearInterval(interval);

}
const classes = useStyles();
  return (
      <div>
      <h5>Logging for Archive load  process</h5>
      <button onClick={handlestart}>start</button>
      <button onClick={handleEnd}>End</button>
      <div className={classes.progressdiv}>
          {texts.map((a, index) => (
              <div>
                {index}. {a}
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect:

```js
function App() {
  const [texts, setTexts] = React.useState([]);
  const [start, setStart] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;
    if (start) {
      interval = setInterval(function () {
        setTexts((t) => [...t, 'asad']);
      }, 2000);
    }
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [start]);
  const handlestart = () => {
    setStart(true);
  };
  const handleEnd = () => {
    setStart(false);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h5>Logging for Archive load process</h5>
      <button onClick={handlestart}>start</button>
      <button onClick={handleEnd}>End</button>
      <div>
        {texts.map((a, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            {index}. {a}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```